# How can I find what fixtures a test uses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I want to automatically mark tests based on which fixtures they use. For instance, if a test uses a fixture named `spark`, I'd like to add a marker called `uses_spark` so that I can automatically ignore them.

I know I can use `pytest_collection_modifyitems` in `conftest.py` to add markers.

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
  for item in items:
    if uses_spark_fixture(item):
      item.add_marker(pytest.mark.spark)

def uses_spark_fixture(item):
  ???
```

How do I implement `uses_spark_fixture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each item stores the list of used fixtures in the `fixturenames` attribute. the check is thus quite simple:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        if 'spark_fixture' in item.fixturenames:
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.spark)
```